# How to add a listenner to a Switch Button?

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, oncheckedchanged

Im trying to add a listenner to  Switch but for some reason it does not listen to the check events.

I implemented  `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` on my activity like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity 
           implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
```

here is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

    newOrSavedSwitch = (Switch)  findViewById(R.id.new_or_saved_switch);        
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Monitored switch is " + (isChecked ? "on" : "off"),
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The toast does not show, also I dont see errors in logcat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to register the `OnCheckedChangeListener` onto the `CompoundButton` with [`setOnCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener%28android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener%29):

```
newOrSavedSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

register switch using setOnCheckedChangeListener(this) method.

You may try just using inner class type listener

```
 toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {                   
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wi-Fi Enabled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {                   
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wi-Fi Disabled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

This works great for me.

You may also like to have an look at this post [Android Switch Example](http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-turn-off-turn-on-wifi-in-android-using-code/)

Comment: +1 for alternative answer, by the way what is the difference when you do it this way?